# Limiting str characters from mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script that pulls query information from MySQL database.

```
 if 'IMPALA_AUDIT' in table:
        query = "SELECT ID, EVENT_TIME, ALLOWED, SERVICE_NAME, 
lower((REPLACE(USERNAME,'@UED.NET', ''))), IMPERSONATOR, IP_ADDR, 
OPERATION, QUERY_ID, SESSION_ID, STATUS, DATABASE_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, 
TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE, REPLACE(REPLACE(OPERATION_TEXT,CHAR(X'0D'),' 
'),CHAR(X'0A'),' ') FROM " + table + ";"
        pull.create_data_file(query, 'IMPALA_AUDIT.DATA1')
```

I'm trying to limit the results from OPERATION_TEXT to 10 characters.
This is what I've tried:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE LEFT((OPERATION_TEXT, CHAR(X'0D'),' '),10),CHAR(X'0A'),' ')
```

and several other similar changes with no luck.

Comment: what's the column definition of `OPERATION_TEXT`?
Are you trying to replace whitespace characters, and not count them towards your 10? Are you getting an error message, or results you don't like?

Comment: This is my error: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT((OPERATION_TEXT, CHAR(X'0D'),' '),5),CHAR(X'0A'),' ') FROM IMPALA_AUDIT_EVE' at line 1")

Comment: This is my result from my original query. OPERATION_TEST begins with insert INTO. 
  
 :2^\1510895172000^\1^\impala^\a00848^\^\172.19.22.11^\DML^\d24796babd93be63:d8d6e6a6814a4093^\1548e99a9a4101c1:1cb88b5a8c3830ab^\^\ed_customer_touchpoint^\TABLE^\chat_acty^\INSERT^\insert INTO ed_customer_touchpoint.chat_acty SELECT    chat_acty_rec_id,   cin,   tokn_sesn_id.......

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to convert from hexadecimal, so I'm going to guess OPERATION_TEXT is stored as a hexadecimal format? Or do you want the first ten characters of the hex string?

Comment: I believe I want the first 10 characters of the hex string. I did not write the original script, the hex characters are new to me. Basically I want result of OPERATION_TEXT to be "insert INTO" and not "insert INTO ed_customer_touchpoint...etc"

Comment: This is not supposed to be a guessing game on my part. Please clean up your question, evaluate my proposed solution, and provide information on what output you're getting and what output you expect. Copy and pasting a scrap of the insert script doesn't cut it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to limit the output with

```
LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(OPERATION_TEXT,CHAR(X'0D'),' '),CHAR(X'0A'),' '),5)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it is unclear why `LEFT(CONVERT(OPERATION_TEXT USING utf8),10)` or `LEFT(UNHEX(OPERATION_TEXT),10)` doesn't return your desired result. [here is a link to the relevant documentation on CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert). [Here's the link for UNHEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex)

I'm pretty sure the source of your error is not escaping the single quotes in your representation of the hex format, which is not the MySQL way to do it.